# Selector: Fastest way to get descendants of a specific level only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, nested-table

I have a table like:

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </tbod>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using jQuery and there exists a stored selector to get the most outer table:

```
var x = $('#table')
```

Starting from that If want to get all *first level* `<tr>`-elements.

If I use one of those:

```
x.find('tbody > tr');
x.children('tbody').children();
```

… the first one will naturally select all nested `<tr>`-elements as well. The latter seems over-complicated and involves multiple queries.

Is there a way to make this faster/more efficient?

Comment: Try with `jQuery filters..`

Comment: FYI, "childen" are always elements of the "first level". You want to get the children only, not all *descendants* (see  [this graphic](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/09/20/relationship-in-the-dom/)) Why do you think what you have is not efficient? How did you test the performance?

Comment: I mean *children of course

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks the word `descendant` didn't came to my mind, when writing this question - I edited the title by now. I knew that `children` wouldn't fit 100% as there's that `tbody` inbetween. And I didn't test it, no. I just thought that there must be some way to get this straight with only one query instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, `x.find('tbody > tr')` would find all `<tr>`s. You would need to do `x.find('> tbody > tr')`, assuming `x` is `x` from your example.

I ran a test and this with both and this was my finding.

```
.children(): 3.013ms
>: 0.626ms
```

so the `>` method is faster than the `.children()` method. The function calls add up... barely.

Here's my JavaScript for the testing.

```
var $table = $('#table'), $usingChildren, $usingAngleBracket;

console.time('.children()');
$usingChildren = $table.children('tbody').children('tr');
console.timeEnd('.children()');

console.time('>');
$usingAngleBracket = $table.find('> tbody > tr');
console.timeEnd('>');

console.log( $usingChildren, $usingAngleBracket );
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know I can use a selector starting with `>`, like `> tbody > tr`. That's pretty nice and looks even faster according to your measurement. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

the fastest way to get `direct children` of a `parent` is `.children`, so what you can do is:

```
$('tbody').children('tr')
```

`.find()` will search `child of child` too, so you may not want to use that.

Comment: Thats actually, what I wrote in my question, getting the the children of the first `tbody`: `x.children('tbody').children();`. ;)

Comment: this really is a faster way to do dat so i wrote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use jQuery's [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method to find the first `<tr>` element,

```
$('#mytable tr').first()
```

Although, as you wish to find the first `<tr>` that has ***nested*** child elements, you can filter it with `.has()`. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/cwL4q/3/

```
$("#mytable tr").has('tbody').first().css("background-color", "red" );
```

Although, I would strongly suggest simply labelling the 'nested' `<tr>`'s with a class, then you can simply access them much quicker as you know.

```
$('.nestedrow');
```

For the HTML below:

```
<table id="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr class="nestedrow">
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr></tr>
                        </tbod>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I actually want to get *all* children of the first level, not only the first one of the first level.

Comment: @lampshade Ahh, I see the first **nested** level of `<tr>`'s?

Comment: @lampshade Adjusted answer, I think your title is slightly confusing though! =)